# Como usar EF Core com herança corretamente e capturar objetos de chave estrangeira?

Tags: json, serialização, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou usando o Entity Framework Core, e eu tenho um modelo que usa herança. Uso o padrão TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) que me mapeia todas as classes da mesma super classe na mesma tabela e usa uma coluna discriminator para distingui-las.

Quando eu gravo um dado no banco, todos os dados vão corretamente. Porém quando tento recuperar esses dados, não consigo capturar os objeto relacionados a chave estrangeira.

```
public class Computador : ProdutoBase
{  
    public int CpuId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Processador Cpu { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public MemoriaRam Memoria { get; set; }
    public int HdId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public HD Hd { get; set; }
    public int PlacaMaeId { get; set; }
    public PlacaMae PlacaMae { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Preco { get; set; }
    public int CodigoRef { get; set; }

    protected Computador() : base()
    {

    }

    public Computador(string marca, string modelo, decimal preco) : base()
    {
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        Preco = preco;
    }

    public Computador(string marca, string modelo, decimal preco, Processador cpu, MemoriaRam ram, HD hd, PlacaMae placaMae) : base()
    {
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        Preco = preco;

        Cpu = cpu;
        Memoria = ram;
        Hd = hd;
        PlacaMae = placaMae;
    }

    public void AddComponentes(Processador cpu, MemoriaRam ram, HD hd, PlacaMae placaMae)
    {
        Cpu = cpu;
        Memoria = ram;
        Hd = hd;
        PlacaMae = placaMae;
    }
}
```

Banco de Dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Json

```
{"cpuId":1,"cpu":null,"memoria":null,"hdId":2,"hd":null,"placaMaeId":4,"placaMae":null,"preco":5000.00,"codigoRef":0,"id":5,"marca":"Dell","modelo":"Inspiron","urlImagem":"http://www.marcheartdevie.com.br/shop/img/p/br-default-home_default.jpg"}
```

Comment: Como você recuperou! faltou passar isso.

Comment: Estou chamando os métodos de get em uma classe de repositórios através do controller do WebAPI. Os métodos na classe base de repositório são.

        public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return Entity;
        }

        public TEntity Get(int id)
        {
            return Entity.Find(id);
        }

Comment: Se pode trabalhar com `Include` carregamento adiantado ... !!! porque `GetAll()` retorna um `IQueryable<T>` e ainda é feito a consulta no banco ... ou então criar um outro método para dar um `Include` há algumas possibilidades